# Conflicting types for 'sleep'

Tags: c

Why do I keep getting the error message "Conflicting types for 'sleep'" when I try running my program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void congratulateStudent (char *student, char *course, int numDays)
{
    printf("%s has done as much %s Programming as I could fit into %d days. \n", student, course, numDays);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    congratulateStudent("Mark", "Cocoa", 5);
    sleep(2);
    congratulateStudent("Bo", "Objective-C", 2);
    sleep(2);
    congratulateStudent("Mike", "Python", 5);
    sleep(2);
    congratulateStudent("Ted", "iOS", 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I included the file #include <unistd.h> and that seemed to solve the problem, although I don't know why.

Comment: You current question doesn't give the warning message, do it. Who should guess what you've initialy asked? When reporting compiler diagnostics it's important to cite the exact message since it may contain information that you probably didn't recognize.

Answer (score 6):

Every library function has a corresponding header file that declares the function. For the `sleep` function, that header file is `unistd.h`. The documentation for each function tells you which header file to use.

If you don't include the correct header file, then the compiler will complain bitterly.  Don't make the compiler unhappy, always include the correct header file.